# Gunicorn on EC2 keeps giving WORKER TIMEOUT when called externally

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-12.04, gunicorn

I am trying to get my flask app running on gunicorn fronted by nginx. I wanted to test things as I go so I got everything working using the flask development server internally and externally to aws. I then started up gunicorn and tired it. A simple call to /status, which returns 'running' worked, but the workers kept timing out and restarting.

I rolled up my sleeves, and started simplifying. I can now reproduce this with a simple wsgi script:

```
def application(env, start_response):
start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/html')])
return ["Hello!"]
```

The gunicorn command line that I have is:

```
var/www/py_api/app/var/www/py_api/venv/bin/python /var/www/py_api/venv/bin/gunicorn -b <private_IP>:4000  test_server
```

I have tried to bind to 0.0.0.0 with similar results. Binding to 127.0.0.1 only works internally, but does not reproduce the problem.

I am running everything on Ubuntu 12.04 on an EC2 medium in the default VPC.

I am running everything out of virtualenv. Here is the pip freeze output:

```
Babel==1.3
Flask==0.10.1
Flask-Babel==0.9
Flask-Login==0.2.10
Flask-Mail==0.9.0
Flask-SQLAlchemy==1.0
Flask-User==0.4.9
Flask-WTF==0.9.5
Jinja2==2.7.2
MarkupSafe==0.21
SQLAlchemy==0.9.4
WTForms==1.0.5
Werkzeug==0.9.4
argparse==1.2.1
awscli==1.3.11
bcdoc==0.12.2
blinker==1.3
botocore==0.45.0
colorama==0.2.5
docutils==0.11
hashids==1.0.0
itsdangerous==0.24
jmespath==0.4.1
oursql==0.9.3.1
passlib==1.6.2
py-bcrypt==0.4
pyasn1==0.1.7
pycrypto==2.6.1
python-dateutil==2.2
pytz==2014.2
requestes==0.0.1
requests==2.3.0
rsa==3.1.2
six==1.6.1
speaklater==1.3
virtualenv==1.11.4
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

I am reluctant to move forward with nginx until I get this resolved.

**Summery**: 
If I curl locally everything works fine. If I curl from external, either through a ELB or direct to the machine, I get timeouts. It is not just curl.

**Theory**: 
I have ready about problems with Gunicorn and elbs, I am wondering if the change to putting all ec2 instances in at least a default vpc, means that any external traffic goes through a transparent elb.

Comment: Have you ever found the cause of this? I've been working around it by putting an nginx between ELB and gunicorn, but I'd love to understand what's really going on...

Comment: I did fix, but unfortunately I do not remember what I had to do. It was a configuration change. Something that I had done wrong in the config or the command line. I think it was actually multiple factors, which made it difficult to troubleshoot. If I remember it I will post. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding timeout with some value based on your requirement. 
In your service file (/etc/systemd/system/`your_app`.service) add new paramter `-t 900` to the `ExecStart`.

Example mentioned below

`ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/env_name/bin/gunicorn --error-logfile ./error.log -w 4 --access-logfile ./access.log -t 900 -b unix:app_name.sock -m 007 wsgi:app`

For more information check this link http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#timeout for more info.